# When I use template literals and run a code, I get undefined in result

Tags: javascript

If I write:

```
let x = 10;
let y = 20;

console.log(`Okay this is the answer: ${x+y}`);
```

The result that I get is:

```
Okay this is the answer: 30
=> undefined
```

```js
let x = 10;
let y = 20;

console.log(`Okay this is the answer: ${x+y}`);
```

I don't understand what this `=> undefined` means in the result displayed in the console.

Note: Although the snippet given above doesn't show `=> undefined`, if we run the code in browser's console or in [repl.it](http://repl.it/languages/javascript), it is shown.

Comment: Where did you get undefined? We don't see it

Comment: your code is okay. i don't understand the error you have said.

Comment: I've edited the question. Please try it in your browser or in repl.it.

Comment: @SagunRajLage If you don't log anything it still returns `undefined` in the console. I believe that it is just printing out the `return` value at the end. But since you don't return anything it just prints undefined. Eg: take a look at [this](https://repl.it/repls/ChubbySophisticatedBotany) example, at the end I `return 0` and that is what is printed

Comment: Your premise as stated in the question title is flawed.  This isn't happening because you used a template literal;  This is happening because of the way that the browser console works.